# How to redeliver a STOMP message to the consumer in case of any processing failure?

Tags: spring-boot, jms, stomp, activemq-artemis

**High-level architecture**

JMS (Producer/Consumer) <----> Artemis(STOMP) <----> Websocket-Broker-Relay-Service <----> STOMP-over-Websocket-client (Producer/Consumer)

**Some observations**

1. In STOMP consumer, with *client-individual* ack-subscription, whether I *NACK* or *ACK*, the message is discarded by Artemis. I want the message to be redelivered to the same or any other consumer. Is there a way to achieve it?
2. In JMS consumer, the durable-message is not delivered if the consumer was down when the message was received on Artemis. My expectation was that once the consumer service comes back up again, the durable message will be delivered.

```java
class StompSessionHandlerImpl implements StompSessionHandler {
    @Override
    public void afterConnected(StompSession session, StompHeaders connectedHeaders) {
        session.setAutoReceipt(Boolean.FALSE);
        StompHeaders headers1 = new StompHeaders();
        headers1.setDestination("/queue/msg");
        headers1.add("durable-subscription-name", messagingUtil.getServiceSubscriptionChannel());
        headers1.add("Authorization", "Bearer ".concat(token));
        headers1.setAck("client-individual");
        session.subscribe(headers1, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void handleException(StompSession session, StompCommand command, StompHeaders headers, byte[] payload, Throwable exception) {
        session.acknowledge(Objects.requireNonNull(headers.getMessageId()), false);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleTransportError(StompSession session, Throwable exception) {
        synchronized (StompSessionHandlerImpl.msgSenderLock) {
            if (exception instanceof ConnectionLostException && !getStompSession().isConnected()) {
                initStompSession();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
        return COMessage.class;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
        if (payload == null) return;
        COMessage msg = (COMessage) payload;
     try {
        stompMessagingService.handleReceivedMessages(msg);
        self.stompMessagingService.getStompSession().acknowledge(headers.getMessageId(), true);
       } catch (Exception e) {
           self.stompMessagingService.getStompSession().acknowledge(headers.getMessageId(), false);
       }

    }


    @PreDestroy
    public void cleanUp() {
        self.stompMessagingService.getStompSession().disconnect();
    }

}
```

```java
class WebSocketConfig extends WebSocketMessagingAutoConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public WebSocketStompClient stompClient() {
        WebSocketClient simpleWebSocketClient = new StandardWebSocketClient();
        List<Transport> transports = List.of(new WebSocketTransport(simpleWebSocketClient));
        SockJsClient sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(transports);
        WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
        converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        stompClient.setMessageConverter(converter);
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        scheduler.setPoolSize(10000);
        scheduler.initialize();
        stompClient.setTaskScheduler(scheduler);
        stompClient.setDefaultHeartbeat(new long[]{20000, 20000});
        stompClient.setReceiptTimeLimit(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer().setDefaultMaxTextMessageBufferSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        return stompClient;
    }
}
```

```java
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    private String host;

    private String password;

    private String user;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/queue", "/topic", "/exchange")
                .setRelayHost(host)
                .setClientLogin(user)
                .setClientPasscode(password)
                .setSystemHeartbeatSendInterval(20000)
                .setSystemLogin(user)
                .setSystemPasscode(password)
                .setUserDestinationBroadcast("/topic/unresolved-user")
                .setUserRegistryBroadcast("/topic/log-user-registry");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/device");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/websocket").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS().setWebSocketEnabled(Boolean.TRUE);
        registry.setErrorHandler(new StompSubProtocolErrorHandler());
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultSimpUserRegistry getDefaultSimpRegistry() {
        return new DefaultSimpUserRegistry();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration registry) {
        registry.setMessageSizeLimit(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        registry.setSendBufferSizeLimit(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        registry.setTimeToFirstMessage(300000);
        registry.setSendTimeLimit(300000);
        registry.addDecoratorFactory(new WebSocketHandlerDecoratorFactory() {
            @Override
            public WebSocketHandler decorate(WebSocketHandler webSocketHandler) {
                return new EmaWebSocketHandlerDecorator(webSocketHandler);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

```java
class ArtemisConfig extends ArtemisAutoConfiguration {

    @Bean("mqConnectionFactory")
    public ConnectionFactory senderActiveMQConnectionFactory() {

        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
               new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://".concat(host.concat(":").concat(port)));
        connectionFactory.setUser(user);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(password);
        connectionFactory.setConnectionTTL(-1L);
        connectionFactory.setClientID(clientID);
        connectionFactory.setEnableSharedClientID(true);
        connectionFactory.setPreAcknowledge(Boolean.FALSE);
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean("mqCachingConnectionFactory")
    @Primary
    public ConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory() {
        return new CachingConnectionFactory(senderActiveMQConnectionFactory());
    }

    @Bean("jmsTemplate")
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(cachingConnectionFactory());
        jmsTemplate.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter);
        jmsTemplate.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(ActiveMQJMSConstants.INDIVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        jmsTemplate.setMessageIdEnabled(Boolean.TRUE);
        jmsTemplate.setTimeToLive(Integer.MAX_VALUE); // TODO : review
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void cleanUp() {
        if (connection.isStarted()) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                log.error("Failed to close the JMS connection {0}", e);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using ActiveMQ Artemis a STOMP [`ACK`](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#ACK) frame tells the broker that the message has been consumed successfully so it should be removed from the queue. A STOMP [`NACK`](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#NACK) frame tells the broker that the message was *not* consumed successfully so the broker will discard it. The exact behavior here is not specified by the STOMP specification. It only says:

> `NACK` is the opposite of `ACK`. It is used to tell the server that the client did not consume the message. The server can then either send the message to a different client, discard it, or put it in a dead letter queue. The exact behavior is server specific.
>
> `NACK` takes the same headers as `ACK`: `id` (REQUIRED) and `transaction` (OPTIONAL).
>
> NACK applies either to one single message (if the subscription's ack mode is `client-individual`) or to all messages sent before and not yet ACK'ed or NACK'ed (if the subscription's ack mode is `client`).

If you want the message to be redelivered you should neither ack nor nack the message and when the consumer's connection is closed the message will be placed back onto the queue for delivery to another (or the same) client.

In the future I expect this behavior will be configurable.

Comment: thanks for your response. The messages are time-critical. If we do not NACK/ACK, in that case for the message to be redelivered the connection-TTL needs to be very low. And even if the connection-TTL is low, as long as there are new incoming messages, the connection will stay alive, in which case the message will be stuck in the queue awaiting connection closure. What do you suggest? or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not clear where connection-TTL enters the picture here, and I don't see why new messages arriving will force the connection to remain alive. If your application needs to close the connection to trigger a redelivery it can simply close the connection, no? The application is in control of its own connection. At least, that's true in most use-cases? Is your use-case different?

Comment: _Apache ActiveMQ Artemis makes all of this configurable via a connection TTL. Basically, the TTL determines how long the server will keep a connection alive in the absence of any data arriving from the client. The client will automatically send "ping" packets periodically to prevent the server from closing it down. If the server doesn't receive any packets on a connection for the connection TTL time, then it will automatically close all the sessions on the server that relate to that connection_  
From this paragraph in the docs, I got that understanding.

Comment: Although, From your last comment, I understand, you mean in the event of failure, I should just deliberately close the connection and reconnect from the consumer as a workaround. It would be great if this behaviour could be configurable as you mentioned in your response.

Comment: The connection TTL is there to make sure the broker closes the connection and cleans up any server-side resources in case of a client or network failure or misbehaving client that simply doesn't close its connection properly. It doesn't really have any bearing on this use-case. As noted, you should close your connection deliberately to trigger redelivery. As far as making the behavior configurable please consider contributing a solution. ActiveMQ Artemis is, after all, open-source, and code contributions are always welcome.